# jQuery and PHP Remote Upload

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, file-upload

I need help with a Remote Upload Script that has a page named 'uploadHandler.php'. I need to create a Remote Upload Script with jQuery PHP File Upload (jQuery File Upload). I would like to upload through this script a file that comes from a different server by entering only the URL. How can this be done?

Let me explain. I have a form that sends a request to uploadHandler.php when a user uploads a file from his computer. The problem is that the type is 'multipart/form-data' so I cannot upload via URL. I tried to put a URL but the system returns

```
[{"name":"","size":0,"type":null,"error":"File received has zero size."}]
```

So, what should I do to make sure that the file is processed by uploadHandler.php and then stored correctly? I had thought to download the file from the server and then upload it to do so treated. But how? I enclose the contents of uploadHandler.php for those who want to read it. Thank you in advance for your help, and I apologize for the grammar and vocabulary wrong: I'm not English.

```
class uploadHandler
{    
    private $options;

function __construct($options = null)
{
    // get accepted file types
    $acceptedFileTypes = getAcceptedFileTypes();

    $this->options = array(
        'script_url' => $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
        'upload_dir' => _CONFIG_FILE_STORAGE_PATH,
        'upload_url' => dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/files/',
        'param_name' => 'files',
        'delete_hash' => '',
        // The php.ini settings upload_max_filesize and post_max_size
        // take precedence over the following max_file_size setting:
        'max_file_size' => $this->get_max_upload_size(),
        'min_file_size' => 1,
        'accept_file_types' => COUNT($acceptedFileTypes) ? ('/(\.|\/)(' . str_replace(".", "", implode("|", $acceptedFileTypes)) . ')$/i') : '/.+$/i',
        'max_number_of_files' => null,
        'discard_aborted_uploads' => true,
        'image_versions' => array(
            'thumbnail' => array(
                'upload_dir' => dirname(__FILE__) . '/thumbnails/',
                'upload_url' => dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/thumbnails/',
                'max_width' => 80,
                'max_height' => 80
            )
        )
    );
    if ($options)
    {
        $this->options = array_replace_recursive($this->options, $options);
    }
}

private function get_max_upload_size()
{
    // Initialize current user
    $Auth = Auth::getAuth();

    // max allowed upload size
    $maxUploadSize = SITE_CONFIG_FREE_USER_MAX_UPLOAD_FILESIZE;
    if ($Auth->loggedIn())
    {
        // check if user is a premium/paid user
        if ($Auth->level != 'free user')
        {
            $maxUploadSize = SITE_CONFIG_PREMIUM_USER_MAX_UPLOAD_FILESIZE;
        }
    }

    // if php restrictions are lower than permitted, override
    $phpMaxSize = getPHPMaxUpload();
    if ($phpMaxSize < $maxUploadSize)
    {
        $maxUploadSize = $phpMaxSize;
    }

    return $maxUploadSize;
}

private function get_file_object($file_name)
{
    $file_path = $this->options['upload_dir'] . $file_name;
    if (is_file($file_path) && $file_name[0] !== '.')
    {
        $file = new stdClass();
        $file->name = $file_name;
        $file->size = filesize($file_path);
        $file->url = $this->options['upload_url'] . rawurlencode($file->name);
        foreach ($this->options['image_versions'] as $version => $options)
        {
            if (is_file($options['upload_dir'] . $file_name))
            {
                $file->{$version . '_url'} = $options['upload_url']
                        . rawurlencode($file->name);
            }
        }
        $file->delete_url = '~d?' . $this->options['delete_hash'];
        $file->info_url = '~i?' . $this->options['delete_hash'];
        $file->delete_type = 'DELETE';
        return $file;
    }
    return null;
}

private function get_file_objects()
{
    return array_values(array_filter(array_map(
                                    array($this, 'get_file_object'), scandir($this->options['upload_dir'])
                            )));
}

private function create_scaled_image($file_name, $options)
{
    $file_path = $this->options['upload_dir'] . $file_name;
    $new_file_path = $options['upload_dir'] . $file_name;
    list($img_width, $img_height) = @getimagesize($file_path);
    if (!$img_width || !$img_height)
    {
        return false;
    }
    $scale = min(
            $options['max_width'] / $img_width, $options['max_height'] / $img_height
    );
    if ($scale > 1)
    {
        $scale = 1;
    }
    $new_width = $img_width * $scale;
    $new_height = $img_height * $scale;
    $new_img = @imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    switch (strtolower(substr(strrchr($file_name, '.'), 1)))
    {
        case 'jpg':
        case 'jpeg':
            $src_img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file_path);
            $write_image = 'imagejpeg';
            break;
        case 'gif':
            $src_img = @imagecreatefromgif($file_path);
            $write_image = 'imagegif';
            break;
        case 'png':
            $src_img = @imagecreatefrompng($file_path);
            $write_image = 'imagepng';
            break;
        default:
            $src_img = $image_method = null;
    }
    $success = $src_img && @imagecopyresampled(
                    $new_img, $src_img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $img_width, $img_height
            ) && $write_image($new_img, $new_file_path);
    // Free up memory (imagedestroy does not delete files):
    @imagedestroy($src_img);
    @imagedestroy($new_img);
    return $success;
}

private function has_error($uploaded_file, $file, $error)
{
    if ($error)
    {
        return $error;
    }
    if (!preg_match($this->options['accept_file_types'], $file->name))
    {
        return 'acceptFileTypes';
    }
    if ($uploaded_file && is_uploaded_file($uploaded_file))
    {
        $file_size = filesize($uploaded_file);
    } else
    {
        $file_size = $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'];
    }
    if ($this->options['max_file_size'] && (
            $file_size > $this->options['max_file_size'] ||
            $file->size > $this->options['max_file_size'])
    )
    {
        return 'maxFileSize';
    }
    if ($this->options['min_file_size'] &&
            $file_size < $this->options['min_file_size'])
    {
        return 'minFileSize';
    }
    if (is_int($this->options['max_number_of_files']) && (
            count($this->get_file_objects()) >= $this->options['max_number_of_files'])
    )
    {
        return 'maxNumberOfFiles';
    }
    return $error;
}

private function handle_file_upload($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error)
{
    $fileUpload = new stdClass();
    $fileUpload->name = basename(stripslashes($name));
    $fileUpload->size = intval($size);
    $fileUpload->type = $type;
    $fileUpload->error = null;

    $extension = end(explode(".", $fileUpload->name));
    $fileUpload->error = $this->has_error($uploaded_file, $fileUpload, $error);
    if (!$fileUpload->error)
    {
        if (strlen(trim($fileUpload->name)) == 0)
        {
            $fileUpload->error = 'Filename not found.';
        }
    }
    elseif (intval($size) == 0)
    {
        $fileUpload->error = 'File received has zero size.';
    }
    elseif (intval($size) > $this->options['max_file_size'])
    {
        $fileUpload->error = 'File received is larger than permitted.';
    }

    if (!$fileUpload->error && $fileUpload->name)
    {
        if ($fileUpload->name[0] === '.')
        {
            $fileUpload->name = substr($fileUpload->name, 1);
        }
        $newFilename = MD5(microtime());

        // figure out upload type
        $file_size = 0;

        // select server from pool
        $uploadServerId = getAvailableServerId();
        $db = Database::getDatabase(true);
        $uploadServerDetails = $db->getRow('SELECT * FROM file_server WHERE id = ' . $db->quote($uploadServerId));

        // override storage path
        if(strlen($uploadServerDetails['storagePath']))
        {
            $this->options['upload_dir'] = $uploadServerDetails['storagePath'];
            if (substr($this->options['upload_dir'], strlen($this->options['upload_dir']) - 1, 1) == '/')
            {
                $this->options['upload_dir'] = substr($this->options['upload_dir'], 0, strlen($this->options['upload_dir']) - 1);
            }
            $this->options['upload_dir'] .= '/';
        }

        // move remotely via ftp
        if($uploadServerDetails['serverType'] == 'remote')
        {
            // connect ftp
            $conn_id = ftp_connect($uploadServerDetails['ipAddress'], $uploadServerDetails['ftpPort'], 30);
            if($conn_id === false)
            {
                $fileUpload->error = 'Could not connect to file server '.$uploadServerDetails['ipAddress'];
            }

            // authenticate
            if(!$fileUpload->error)
            {
                $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $uploadServerDetails['ftpUsername'], $uploadServerDetails['ftpPassword']);
                if($login_result === false)
                {
                    $fileUpload->error = 'Could not authenticate with file server '.$uploadServerDetails['ipAddress'];
                }
            }

            // create the upload folder
            if(!$fileUpload->error)
            {
                $uploadPathDir = $this->options['upload_dir'] . substr($newFilename, 0, 2);
                if(!ftp_mkdir($conn_id, $uploadPathDir))
                {
                    // Error reporting removed for now as it causes issues with existing folders. Need to add a check in before here
                    // to see if the folder exists, then create if not.
                    // $fileUpload->error = 'There was a problem creating the storage folder on '.$uploadServerDetails['ipAddress'];
                }
            }

            // upload via ftp
            if(!$fileUpload->error)
            {
                $file_path = $uploadPathDir . '/' . $newFilename;
                clearstatcache();
                if ($uploaded_file && is_uploaded_file($uploaded_file))
                {
                    // initiate ftp
                    $ret = ftp_nb_put($conn_id, $file_path, $uploaded_file, 
                                        FTP_BINARY, FTP_AUTORESUME);
                    while ($ret == FTP_MOREDATA)
                    {
                        // continue uploading
                        $ret = ftp_nb_continue($conn_id);
                    }

                    if ($ret != FTP_FINISHED)
                    {
                        $fileUpload->error = 'There was a problem uploading the file to '.$uploadServerDetails['ipAddress'];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $file_size = filesize($uploaded_file);
                        @unlink($uploaded_file);
                    }
                }
            }

            // close ftp connection
            ftp_close($conn_id);
        }
        // move into local storage
        else
        {
            // create the upload folder
            $uploadPathDir = $this->options['upload_dir'] . substr($newFilename, 0, 2);
            @mkdir($uploadPathDir);

            $file_path = $uploadPathDir . '/' . $newFilename;
            clearstatcache();
            if ($uploaded_file && is_uploaded_file($uploaded_file))
            {
                move_uploaded_file($uploaded_file, $file_path);
            }
            $file_size = filesize($file_path);
        }

        // check filesize uploaded matches tmp uploaded
        if ($file_size === $fileUpload->size)
        {
            $fileUpload->url = $this->options['upload_url'] . rawurlencode($fileUpload->name);

            // insert into the db
            $fileUpload->size = $file_size;
            $fileUpload->delete_url = '~d?' . $this->options['delete_hash'];
            $fileUpload->info_url = '~i?' . $this->options['delete_hash'];
            $fileUpload->delete_type = 'DELETE';

            // create delete hash, make sure it's unique
            $deleteHash = md5($fileUpload->name . getUsersIPAddress() . microtime());
            $existingFile = file::loadByDeleteHash($deleteHash);
            while ($existingFile != false)
            {
                $deleteHash = md5($fileUpload->name . getUsersIPAddress() . microtime());
                $existingFile = file::loadByDeleteHash($deleteHash);
            }

            // store in db
            $db = Database::getDatabase(true);
            $dbInsert = new DBObject("file", array("originalFilename", "shortUrl", "fileType", "extension", "fileSize", "localFilePath", "userId", "totalDownload", "uploadedIP", "uploadedDate", "statusId", "deleteHash", "serverId"));

            $dbInsert->originalFilename = $fileUpload->name;
            $dbInsert->shortUrl = 'temp';
            $dbInsert->fileType = $fileUpload->type;
            $dbInsert->extension = $extension;
            $dbInsert->fileSize = $fileUpload->size;
            $dbInsert->localFilePath = str_replace($this->options['upload_dir'], "", $file_path);

            // add user id if user is logged in
            $dbInsert->userId = NULL;
            $Auth = Auth::getAuth();
            if ($Auth->loggedIn())
            {
                $dbInsert->userId = (int) $Auth->id;
            }

            $dbInsert->totalDownload = 0;
            $dbInsert->uploadedIP = getUsersIPAddress();
            $dbInsert->uploadedDate = sqlDateTime();
            $dbInsert->statusId = 1;
            $dbInsert->deleteHash = $deleteHash;
            $dbInsert->serverId = $uploadServerId;

            if (!$dbInsert->insert())
            {
                $fileUpload->error = 'abort';
            }

            // create short url
            $tracker = 1;
            $shortUrl = file::createShortUrlPart($tracker . $dbInsert->id);
            $fileTmp = file::loadByShortUrl($shortUrl);
            while ($fileTmp)
            {
                $shortUrl = file::createShortUrlPart($tracker . $dbInsert->id);
                $fileTmp = file::loadByShortUrl($shortUrl);
                $tracker++;
            }

            // update short url
            file::updateShortUrl($dbInsert->id, $shortUrl);

            // update fileUpload with file location
            $file = file::loadByShortUrl($shortUrl);
            $fileUpload->url = $file->getFullShortUrl();
            $fileUpload->delete_url = $file->getDeleteUrl();
            $fileUpload->info_url = $file->getInfoUrl();
            $fileUpload->stats_url = $file->getStatisticsUrl();
            $fileUpload->short_url = $shortUrl;
        }
        else if ($this->options['discard_aborted_uploads'])
        {
            //@TODO - made ftp compatible
            @unlink($file_path);
            @unlink($uploaded_file);
            if(!isset($fileUpload->error))
            {
                $fileUpload->error = 'maxFileSize';
            }
        }
    }

    return $fileUpload;
}

public function get()
{
    $file_name = isset($_REQUEST['file']) ?
            basename(stripslashes($_REQUEST['file'])) : null;
    if ($file_name)
    {
        $info = $this->get_file_object($file_name);
    } else
    {
        $info = $this->get_file_objects();
    }
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($info);
}

public function post()
{
    $upload = isset($_FILES[$this->options['param_name']]) ?
            $_FILES[$this->options['param_name']] : array(
        'tmp_name' => null,
        'name' => null,
        'size' => null,
        'type' => null,
        'error' => null
            );
    $info = array();
    if (is_array($upload['tmp_name']))
    {
        foreach ($upload['tmp_name'] as $index => $value)
        {
            $info[] = $this->handle_file_upload($upload['tmp_name'][$index], 
                    isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME'] : $upload['name'][$index], 
                    isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_SIZE']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_SIZE'] : $upload['size'][$index], 
                    isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_TYPE'] : $upload['type'][$index], 
                    $upload['error'][$index]
            );
        }
    } else
    {
        $info[] = $this->handle_file_upload($upload['tmp_name'], 
                isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME'] : $upload['name'],
                isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_SIZE']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_SIZE'] : $upload['size'],
                isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_TYPE'] : $upload['type'],
                $upload['error']
        );
    }
    header('Vary: Accept');
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']) &&
            (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'], 'application/json') !== false))
    {
        header('Content-type: application/json');
    } else
    {
        header('Content-type: text/plain');
    }
    echo json_encode($info);
}
}

$upload_handler = new uploadHandler();

header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Cache-Control: private, no-cache');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="files.json"');

// check we are receiving the request from this script
if (!checkReferrer())
{
    // exit
    header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
    exit();
}

switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])
{
    case 'HEAD':
    case 'GET':
        $upload_handler->get();
        break;
    case 'POST':
        $upload_handler->post();
        break;
    default:
        header('HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need downloader. Not uploader. You want to download a file to your server from another server. To achieve that from PHP, you can use cUrl or file_get_contents. In the form, just take the URL and when the form is submitted, download the file from that URL to your server using cUrl or file_get_contents().

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I would like to know how do I treat it with the file uploadHandler.php

Comment: http://hastebin.com/redosigisu.php - I have copy pasted a function that I use. It can download and save a file if you pass on the URL, new filename and folder path as to save the new file. Expect errors as that function was part of a class. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Vishnu Over 2 years ago, and this is relevant for me - but your hastebin doesnt work. Do you still have that function by any chance? How can i process a stored file in the uploadHandler script

Comment: @Karem Hi. I don't remember using hastebin.com ever! But from my comment, I remember the code that I was taking about. I have pasted it here: http://pastebin.com/akpZ1cCU. Hope it helps.